# Objective C parse string for middle chars

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring

This is a bit of a puzzler for me. I have a string that looks like:

```
fanspd<fanspd>3</fanspd>
doorinprocess<doorinprocess>0</doorinprocess>
timeremaining<timeremaining>0</timeremaining>
macaddr<macaddr>60:CB:FB:99:99:C1</macaddr>
ipaddr<ipaddr>10.0.0.6</ipaddr>
model<model>4.4eWHF</model>
softver: <softver>2.14.2</softver>
interlock1: <interlock1>0</interlock1>
interlock2: <interlock2>0</interlock2>
cfm: <cfm>2200</cfm>
power: <power>120</power>
inside: <house_temp>-99</house_temp>
<DNS1>10.0.0.1</DNS1>
attic: <attic_temp>76</attic_temp>
OA: <oa_temp>-99</oa_temp>
server response: <server_response>Ó£àêEE²ç©þ]kõ «jsÐ</server_response>
DIP Switches: <DIPS>11100</DIPS>
Remote Switch: <switch2>1111</switch2>
Setpoint:<Setpoint>0</Setpoint>
```

The string includes the "/n" so I have split it into corrisponding lines that look like

```
fanspd<fanspd>0</fanspd>
```

All I really want is the char(s) in the middle of the line. In the above example it would be 0.

I can match everything with regular expressions but by doing the following:

```
(.*)(<[a-z]+>)(.*)(</[a-z]+>)
```

But what I'd like is something more that would exclude or strip away or remove all the junk and grab the middle chars.

```
(!(.*)(!<[a-z]+>))(.*)(!(</[a-z]+>))
```

I've tried this and it does not work. I've also thought of doing another [NSstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"(with either < or  or >"] but that would leave be with more parsing yet to do and I think there should be a way to get just the chars inbetween the tags with either regular expressions or string compare or some such way to parse out the

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering since it seems to have some similarities with XML if deleting the info before the data between tags and the tags (example: @"0A: ") and then use an XML parser wouldn't be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.
Your regular expression **does not escape the forward slash**.
Your regular expression seems **overly complicated** for what you are trying to do.

If all you want is that lone middle character with regular expressions,

Try this:
**<[a-z]+>(.*)<\/[a-z]+>**

Here's a great tool to play around with:
http://rubular.com

Heck you could probably even get away with:
**<[a-z]+>(.*)<\/**

**EDIT:**

I figured out your problem partially, some of the tags part way down contain characters other than a through z.  So here you go:

**<.+>(.*)<\/.+>**

Comment: I agree with you regarding the over complication. I was simply trying to group things so that I could negate groups. This still does not address the heart of the issue. I'd like to negate everything but the middle character. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @FujiRoyale I'm confused this does exactly that.

Comment: @FujiRoyale notice my regular expression only has a single set of paranthesis.

Comment: @FujiRoyale I tested my regular expression against your string at the link I provided and it works perfectly.  I'm thinking you may not realize exactly what parentheses mean in the Regular Expression language.  In fact, with the regular expression I provided, you would not even have to split it up line by line, because each match represents the next line anyways.

Comment: @FujiRoyale I tested the entire string now, the bottom regular expression should work.

Comment: thanks for the help. I only want to match the 0 in the example case and ignore the everything else. I'm using this to display information to the user on a table.